# readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream using nginx for nodejs reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

in chrome i received **ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH** for API response

nodejs v16.20.2
nginx v1.20.1

server

```
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const server = httpServer.listen(projectConfig.servicePort, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server Listen on ${projectConfig.servicePort} ...`)
})
server.keepAliveTimeout = 1000 * 75
```

ngnix conf

```
upstream nodeapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    #keepalive 50;
}
```

```
location / {
    #set_real_ip_from $ipv4_addresses;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://nodeapp;
    proxy_redirect off;


  #proxy_connect_timeout 15s;
  #proxy_send_timeout 3600s; # ws will open for 1 hour
  #proxy_read_timeout 3600s; # ws will open for 1 hour
  #proxy_buffers 512 256M;
  #proxy_buffer_size 256M;
  #proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  #proxy_buffering off;

}
```

i have tried savaral nginx setting but didnot work when i tried proxy buffer off i have recived half of conent of my api response

i am trying to get full response from API but received
error in chrome  **ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH**

in nginx error log
**readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream**